# ASP.NET webforms site is displaying and saving Japanese characters as?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms, collation

I've tried many different angles to resolve this issue and I'm missing something, I just don't know what yet. I've got the meta tag set to UTF-8 in the masterpage and I've got the following line in the web.config

```xml
  <globalization fileEncoding="ISO-2022-JP" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="ja-JP" uiCulture="ja-JP" />
</system.web>
```

When I save something from a page it comes back into the database as a bunch of question marks if the text is in Japanese. In addition, when I have Japanese data already in the DB from another process it shows up as `????` on the UI.

I have setup a separate server for this, both web and SQL and the SQL DB has been configured for the collation of `Japanese_90_CI_AI_KS_SC` as the default and every database column has been set to `nvarchar`.

Perhaps there is something I have to touch deeper in the C# code to make sure everything is coming across as Unicode when it hits and leave the DB.

Thanks in advance for any pointers or ideas.

Updated with sample of C# code insert code

```cs
public CDI_Scenario InsertScenario(string userName, CDI_Scenario scenario)
{
    string sqlString =
    @"INSERT INTO Scenario 
    (
       [Name], [Description], Active, BaseScenarioFlag, 
       CreateDate, CreatedBy, UpdateDate, UpdatedBy, StartDate, EndDate
    ) 
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ScenarioId
    VALUES 
    (
       @Name, @Description, @Active, @BaseScenarioFlag, 
       @CreateDate, @CreatedBy, @UpdateDate, @UpdatedBy, @StartDate, @EndDate
    )";

    scenario.CreateDate = Framework.Utilities.ConvertTimetoJST((DateTime)scenario.CreateDate);
    scenario.UpdateDate = Framework.Utilities.ConvertTimetoJST((DateTime)scenario.UpdateDate);
    scenario.StartDate = Framework.Utilities.ConvertTimetoJST((DateTime)scenario.StartDate);
    scenario.EndDate = Framework.Utilities.ConvertTimetoJST((DateTime)scenario.EndDate);

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, connection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", scenario.Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", scenario.Description);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", scenario.IsActive);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BaseScenarioFlag", (object)scenario.BaseScenarioFlag ?? DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", userName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", scenario.CreateDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdatedBy", userName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdateDate", scenario.UpdateDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", scenario.StartDate.HasValue ? (object)scenario.StartDate : DBNull.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", scenario.EndDate.HasValue ? (object)scenario.EndDate : DBNull.Value);

            int scenarioId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            scenario.ScenarioId = scenarioId;
        }
    }

    return scenario;
}
```

Comment: How are you inserting data into database? If using any sp check data type, there too.

Comment: From the database's perspective you shouldn't have this problem when using `nvarchar` data types, since they can store the entire set of UCS-2 code points (or UTF-16 when using an `_SC` collation as you are). This is almost certainly an issue in the middle tier code, such as misconfigured `SqlParameter`s or manually constructing SQL query strings with inlined user data. Can you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74083820/edit) your question to include the C# code that's responsible for inserting and/or updating the `nvarchar` column(s) in the database?

Comment: This is a rather old solution with a ton of code in it. I will hunt down some of the C#. This is a combination of some C# doing the work for inserting and some SP doing the inserting. I've edited the majority of the SP to have the proper collation at this point.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm betting all that's needed is updating to this format where the inserts are happening

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar ).Value = scenario.Name;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters in this post, the fix is to update the parameters and any related stored procedures to pass along the nvarchar properly

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar ).Value = scenario.Name;
```